# Draw not fired on fnAjaxReload / Ajax.Reload / __reload

Tags: datatables

I just have the curios issue that the draw event isn't allways fired when I reload my table.

Here is my table init:

```
mCommissionTable = $("#CommissionTable").dataTable({ "bJQueryUI": false, "sDom": 'lfrtip', "columns": [ { "data": "CommissionId" }, { "data": "Description" }, { "data": "CommissionTypeDisplayName" }, { "data": "DivisionCode" }, { "data": "EmployeeName" }, { "data": "EmployeeNumber" }, { "data": "PeriodFrom" }, { "data": "PeriodTill" }, { "data": "ApprovalStatusDisplayName" }, { "data": "StatusDisplayName" }, { "data": "Comment" } ] });
```

Here is my Refresh:

```
function onButtonClickA() { mCommissionTable.fnReloadAjax("GridCommunication.aspx?do=GetCommission" + mFilter, RefreshSelectedRows); }
```

Here is the RefreshSelectedRows:

```
function RefreshSelectedRows() { alert('fired!'); }
```

So everything works fine, table will not be loaded until I click the button the first time, everystime I click the button the table will be loaded. But in fact the callback (RefreshSelectedRows) is not fired every time.

In the DataTables.js code I found the __reload-method in which the API register the callback-event one time, Line 7140:

```
if (callback) {
    var api = new _Api(settings);

    api.one('draw', function () {
        callback(api.ajax.json());
    });
}
```

When I track it to that with Visual Studio and set breakpoint the Api,one-command will be hit with 100%, so it is registerred. The callback isself (what only happens when the event is fired) get hit randomly. I can't reproduce it. it just happened. I click 20 times on the button, 15 times it is okay, 5 times not...

I tried to track it down, but as far as I can see in the _fnReDraw method, where the fnDraw is called and the draw event in triggered everything is okay...

So... bug?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug!
It was an old IE Version!

As soon as I started it with IE9+ it works like charm!